# Plotly figure is not displayed even though it's not empty

Tags: jupyter-notebook, html-table, plotly

I created this function using plotly but, when calling it, nothing is displayed, only a huge white space which has the same size of the table that there should be. I checked whether the figure is empty or not (print(fig)) or whether the initial input are not correct (print(VaR)) but everything is printed out, but not the figure!

Any suggestion?

```
def RiskMeasure(VaR, CVaR, initial_price,percentilesamev,volaforecast, histovol):
    # Create a table trace
    lossvarperc = (VaR/initial_price - 1) * 100
    table_trace = go.Table(
        header=dict(values=['Measure of Risk', 'Value']),
        cells=dict(values=[['VaR (Value at Risk)', 'CVaR (Expected Shortfall)', 'Loss will be greater than: (5% probability) ','Average Loss','Forecast Volatility vs Historical','The probability of a lower price than today is: '],
                           [round(VaR, 3), round(CVaR, 3), str(round(initial_price - VaR,3)) +' ('+ (str(round(lossvarperc,2)) +'%')+')' , round(initial_price - CVaR,3), str(round(volaforecast*100, 2)) +'% vs ' + str(round(histovol))+'%', f'{percentilesamev}%']], height=40)
    )

    # Create layout
    layout = go.Layout(
        title='VaR (Value at Risk) and CVaR (Expected Shortfall)',
        title_x=0.5,  # Center the title horizontally
        height=400,   # Adjust the height of the table
        margin=dict(t=50, b=10)  # Adjust the margin
    )

    # Create figure with table trace and layout
    fig = go.Figure(data=table_trace, layout=layout)
    print(fig)
    fig.show()
    VaR
```

This is the print of the fig:

```
Figure({
'data': [{'cells': {'height': 40,
                    'values': [['VaR (Value at Risk)', 'CVaR (Expected
                               Shortfall)', 'Loss will be greater than: (5%
                               probability) ', 'Average Loss', 'Forecast
                               Volatility vs Historical', 'The probability of a
                               lower price than today is: '], [7442.781,
                               7102.915, '994.119 (-11.78%)', 1333.985, '12.04%
                               vs 7%', '27%']]},
          'header': {'values': ['Measure of Risk', 'Value']},
          'type': 'table'}],
'layout': {'height': 400,
           'margin': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
           'template': '...',
           'title': {'text': 'VaR (Value at Risk) and CVaR (Expected Shortfall)', 'x': 0.5}}
})
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error you're getting. when i run your cells, i am able render the table (see [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZzcEbyW)) have you followed [the instructions](https://plotly.com/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/) outlined in plotly's documentation for jupyter notebooks?